# Join other table in SQL with dual table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, dual-table

SQL Console
[image: screenshot]

```sql
select trunc((:FromDate)+1)-rn as date_Val
  from ( select rownum rn 
           from dual
        connect by level <= ((:FromDate)-(:todate))+1)
 order by trunc(:FromDate)-rn
```

I want to join this column with other tables. When I write in Sub Query return more than one row error show

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a cte and write the rest of your query under it:

```
with dateseq as
(
      select trunc((:FromDate)+1)-rownum as date_val
      from dual 
      connect by level <= ((:FromDate)-(:todate))+1)
)

select * from dateseq inner join ...
```

ps: simplified your query a bit- you don't need the subquery